# Google Chrome Developer tools - CSS file showing as an image resource

Tags: css, google-chrome

I'm running the beta of Google Chrome (12.0.742.60)

My page displays fine, however for some reason, in the Developer Tools 'Resources' tab, it's CSS file is shown under the 'Images' disclosure triangle instead of 'Stylesheets' (where the typekit.com CSS is as expected.)  Grateful for any ideas..

CSS tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/lofkch.css" />
```

CSS response headers (via 'Web Developer' extension):

```
Date: Sat, 21 May 2011 18:52:30 GMT
Content-Length: 9218
Last-Modified: Sat, 21 May 2011 18:40:50 GMT
Server: Apache
ETag: "5ff9-2402-4a3cd93cab080"
Content-Type: text/css
Accept-Ranges: bytes

200 OK
```

Live page - REMOVED - see answer for cause.

Aside: There was an [excellent Google IO session](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N8SS-rUEZPg) on the new features in GDT earlier this month.

Comment: Weird, confirmed in Chrome 10 on Windows. My guess would be it's one of the non-standard CSS properties - what happens if you remove those containing single quotes, for example? The CSS validator chokes on them.  (see [here](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.lofkch.org.uk%2Fstyles%2Flofkch.css&profile=css21&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en))

Comment: What happens if you remove the background:url() images?

Comment: @Knu @Pekka Just tested it on a staging server. Removing the single "background-image: url();" that's erroneously in there fixes it (it copes fine with the other background-image url for an icon.)  Would you say it's worth filing it as a bug in Chromium?

Comment: it depends if it's valid or not to use an empty `background-image` (added my comment as an answer)

Comment: @Knu Can't see it would be valid :-) Thanks for spotting the bug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What happens if you remove the empty `background-image`?

Comment: Yes, it was caused by this line: background-image: url();