# Chrome Reads stylesheet, but puts in in resource/images

Tags: google-chrome, stylesheet

In my website I have a stylesheet that is being rendering in the html with the following line:
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="http://localhost:61000/test/portal_css/Keith%20Theme/keithCustom.css"`

All of these styles are being used on the site, but if I go to the resource tab of the developer tools it has my keithCustom.css stylesheet under the resources/images. This is annoying because it prevents me from being able to look at the stylesheet from the developer tools.

I was wondering if anyone's ever ran into this, or if this might be a bug with chrome.
I can always use Firefox to look at it, but I use chrome as my main browser and I would really like this too work.

Any suggestions or comments would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Turns out someone has already asked this question and I didn't find it in my original search [Google Chrome Developer tools - CSS file showing as an image resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083804/google-chrome-developer-tools-css-file-showing-as-an-image-resource), the solution here worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Chrome isn't interpreting your CSS file as an actual CSS file. Could it be its URL's fault? Does it happen when you browse the same page with its stylesheet on another server? Or try to use a relative path instead of an absolute path on the href attribute.

You could also check the CSS file's encoding. AFAIK the UTF-8 BOM signature can ruin lots of PHP scripts. It might be confusing Chrome, causing it to think the file isn't a plain text stylesheet…

Hope it helps at least clearing some possible suspects!

Comment: The weird thing is that if I look in the network tab it actually does interpret the file as text/css when it loads it