# CSS file is being loaded as Image

Tags: css, browser

I included several CSS files in my website, other works good but one my CSS file (on localhost) :

```
<link href='http://127.0.0.1/ndf/nekib-css.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
```

loads as an image. Here's a screenshot of what I see in the Chrome Developer Tools.

[image]

Double checked the MIME-type, added it on different position but none work.

I am using WAMP.

Any idea what's wrong ?

Comment: What webserver are you using? nginx? apache? Something else?

Comment: @Marwelln IIS has 2 or 3 users too `:p`

Comment: Using WAMP - So it's Apache server.

Comment: `CC files` ? Is this a typo or do you really mean CC ?

Comment: @Panique that's a typo :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be having an issue similar to the post below. Their issue came from having some non-standard css, in their case `background:url()`

[Google Chrome Developer tools - CSS file showing as an image resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083804/google-chrome-developer-tools-css-file-showing-as-an-image-resource)

Comment: Removing the empty background-image property worked! Thank you very much for pointing out the issue.